# Connection to MS SQL Server instance through SSH SOCKS proxy fails

Tags: ssh, sql-server, ssh-tunnel, intranet, socks

I use a local ssh socks proxy (localhost:7070) on my Linux Laptop to connect to my company's intranet over my company's Windows+cygwin laptop, which has intranet access:

Linux --(`ssh -N -D 7070 -p 7022 -l user laptop.company.com`)--> laptop.company.com --> company intranet

The company laptop has a cygwin ssh server running on port 7022.

This proxy works great for email, http, and even connections to my company's MS SQL Servers that *don't* have a special instance running. I use DBeaver with the network settings set to use `localhost:7070` as socks proxy.

But when I attempt to connect to any MS SQL Server *instance*, the connection fails and the terminal in which I am running the above ssh local proxy shows

```
channel 4: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
```

Any idea why accessing instances fails?
Or any other idea how to access my company's intranet via the cygwin laptop with something else than a ssh-tunnel/proxy?

Comment: On what port is your SQL Listening? Try: `EXEC xp_ReadErrorLog 0, 1, N'Server is listening on', N'any', NULL, NULL, 'DESC'`

Comment: They're all connected to the default port 1433. When I run DBeaver on the company windows laptop, where the sshd is running, access to those data bases works, so it must be the ssh socks proxy.